# Why does AWS CloudWatch Logs agent try to create a log group, even though it was already created manually?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application running PHP and I've enabled CloudWatch log streaming. I'm successfully receiving the default logs (e.g. `/var/log/nginx/access.log`), but I also want to include PHP error logs: `/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`.

I followed the [Elastic Beanstalk guide for custom log streaming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html#AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.streaming.custom), which pointed me to the [logs-streamtocloudwatch-linux.config](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/logs-streamtocloudwatch-linux.config) file, so I added the following in my `.ebextensions/logs-streamtocloudwatch-linux.config`:

```
packages:
  yum:
    awslogs: []

files:
  "/etc/awslogs/awscli.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [plugins]
      cwlogs = cwlogs
      [default]
      region = `{"Ref":"AWS::Region"}`

  "/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [general]
      state_file = /var/lib/awslogs/agent-state

  "/etc/awslogs/config/logs.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log

commands:
  "01":
    command: systemctl enable awslogsd.service
  "02":
    command: systemctl restart awslogsd
```

After deploying my app, I was able to verify that `awslogsd` is indeed running by executing `sudo systemctl status awslogsd.service`:

```
● awslogsd.service - awslogs daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/awslogsd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-04-25 04:38:01 UTC; 42min ago
 Main PID: 12100 (aws)
   CGroup: /system.slice/awslogsd.service
           └─12100 /usr/bin/python2 -s /usr/bin/aws logs push --config-file /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf --additional-configs-dir /etc/awslogs/config

Apr 25 04:38:01 ip-172-31-40-232.eu-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started awslogs daemon.
```

However, logs weren't appearing, so I opened `/var/log/awslogs.log` and saw this:

```
2023-04-25 05:23:29,023 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 15899 - MainThread - Loading additional configs from /etc/awslogs/config/logs.conf
2023-04-25 05:23:29,024 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 15899 - MainThread - Missing or invalid value for use_gzip_http_content_encoding config. Defaulting to use gzip encoding.
2023-04-25 05:23:29,024 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 15899 - MainThread - Missing or invalid value for queue_size config. Defaulting to use 10
2023-04-25 05:23:29,024 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 15899 - MainThread - Using default logging configuration.
2023-04-25 05:23:29,030 - cwlogs.push - WARNING - 15899 - MainThread - Unable to get instance id, use ip-172-31-40-232.eu-west-1.compute.internal instead.
2023-04-25 05:23:29,032 - cwlogs.push.stream - INFO - 15899 - Thread-1 - Starting publisher for [112e68af25774e9b29f317ecff7ab444, /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log]
2023-04-25 05:23:29,032 - cwlogs.push.stream - INFO - 15899 - Thread-1 - Starting reader for [112e68af25774e9b29f317ecff7ab444, /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log]
2023-04-25 05:23:29,033 - cwlogs.push.reader - INFO - 15899 - Thread-4 - Replay events end at 440.
2023-04-25 05:23:29,033 - cwlogs.push.reader - INFO - 15899 - Thread-4 - Start reading file from 0.
2023-04-25 05:23:30,073 - cwlogs.push.publisher - WARNING - 15899 - Thread-3 - Caught exception: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation: The specified log stream does not exist.
2023-04-25 05:23:30,082 - cwlogs.push.batch - INFO - 15899 - Thread-3 - Creating log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/Project-env/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log.
2023-04-25 05:23:30,140 - cwlogs.push.batch - WARNING - 15899 - Thread-3 - CreateLogGroup failed with exception An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateLogGroup operation: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-09e9f90439a175bb1 is not authorized to perform: logs:CreateLogGroup on resource: arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Project-env/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log:log-stream: because no identity-based policy allows the logs:CreateLogGroup action
2023-04-25 05:23:30,140 - cwlogs.push.batch - WARNING - 15899 - Thread-3 - An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateLogGroup operation: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-09e9f90439a175bb1 is not authorized to perform: logs:CreateLogGroup on resource: arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Project-env/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log:log-stream: because no identity-based policy allows the logs:CreateLogGroup action
2023-04-25 05:23:30,140 - cwlogs.push.batch - WARNING - 15899 - Thread-3 - Method "_setup_resources" failed, backing off 1.28654892445 seconds, and retrying
```

As you can see, there's a permission error and the CloudWatch agent can't create the log group:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateLogGroup operation: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-09e9f90439a175bb1 is not authorized to perform: logs:CreateLogGroup on resource: arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Project-env/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log:log-stream: because no identity-based policy allows the logs:CreateLogGroup action

Because a log group has to be created just once, I want to create it manually, instead of adding permissions to the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`. So I went to the AWS console, manually created the `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Project-env/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log` log group and verified that using `aws logs describe-log-groups`:

```yaml
- arn: arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Project-env/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log:*
  creationTime: 1682396467491
  logGroupName: /aws/elasticbeanstalk/Project-env/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
  metricFilterCount: 0
  retentionInDays: 7
  storedBytes: 0
```

Then I restarted the CloudWatch agent using `sudo systemctl restart awslogsd.service`, but I was getting the exact same error. I tried restarting the app servers, and even redeploying the app, but nothing helped.

I carefully inspected the name and it matches, so it's not a typo. Therefore, why does the CloudWatch agent try to create a log group that already exists?

I have concerns that this CloudWatch agent is outdated, because the [Elastic Beanstalk docs I linked previously](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html#AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.streaming.custom) mention the [CloudWatch Logs agent reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html), and it states the following:

> This reference is for the older deprecated CloudWatch Logs agent. If you use Instance Metadata Service Version 2 (IMDSv2), you must use the new unified CloudWatch agent. Even if you are not using IMDSv2, we strongly recommend that you use the newer unified CloudWatch agent instead of the older logs agent.

Have I just stumbled upon a bug in deprecated software, or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:** The issue in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055435/3130281) was a typo and CloudWatch was using the incorrect region. That's not the case for me. Here's the result of `sudo cat /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf`:

```
[plugins]
cwlogs = cwlogs
[default]
region = eu-west-1
```

…and my region is indeed `eu-west-1` (Ireland).

Comment: Can you try to add log events to a log stream manually from the aws cli and see if it gives the same error like so `aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name my-logs --log-stream-name 20150601 --log-events file://events`?

Comment: As you mentioned, seems EB is designed in that way. This [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-service.html) explicitly says it needs the Create Log Group permission. It won't fail if the log group already exists. Yet it will still try to create, and hence require the permisison.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set it up by not using the [outdated CloudWatch Logs agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) and instead using the [unified CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html).

It seems that Elastic Beanstalk internally uses the newer CloudWatch agent for the other logs files, because running `sudo amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a status` resulted in:

```json
{
  "status": "running",
  "starttime": "2023-04-25T08:19:22+0000",
  "configstatus": "configured",
  "cwoc_status": "stopped",
  "cwoc_starttime": "",
  "cwoc_configstatus": "not configured",
  "version": "1.247354.0b251981"
}
```

I played around with it and figured out how to make it work with custom log files. You need the following `.ebextensions/custom-cloudwatch-logs.config`:

```yaml
container_commands:
  01_append_logs_config:
    command: |
      amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a append-config -m ec2 -c file:/tmp/custom-cloudwatch-config.json -s

files:
  "/tmp/custom-cloudwatch-config.json":
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      {
        "logs": {
          "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
              "collect_list": [
                {
                  "file_path": "/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log",
                  "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Project-env/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log",
                  "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

This does the following:

1. Creates the necessary `/tmp/custom-cloudwatch-config.json` file containing your custom log file configuration.
2. Runs the `amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl` script with the `append-config` action to include your custom configuration, after the app deploy is ready (see [`container_commands`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands)).

Comment: great answer.  All the Elastic beanstalk documents still refers to old awslogs.  They should update their documents immediately

Comment: Docs for CloudWatch agent configuration file : 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html